# In Java , the data fetched from mysql is not coming in the order

Tags: java, mysql

I am fetching data from mysql, and then storing that data in Hashmap. But the data is not stored in the order it is present in the db table.

Answer (score 0):

A `HashMap` does not guarantee the iteration order of it's elements. To quote the API for `HashMap`:

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time

Presuming you wish to maintain insertion order in a `Map`, use a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). To maintain sorting order, use a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Answer (score 0):

Map is an unordered data structure. It does not store the order that entries were added and does not have a way to iterate over the entries in the order they were added.

There are various other collections that you might consider using if you need to maintain the order of entries. The best choice will depend on your actual requirements.